# AMP error - Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to make my pages compatible with AMP but I'm facing an issue with Google's validation tool and I get the following error:

**Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP**

There are similar topics opened about this issue here but my problem seems to be of a different nature. I don't have a AMP and a non AMP version, I just have AMP pages for all devices, there is only one version of each page.

I have added the canonical reference by referencing the page url:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.gpu-central.com/en/" />
```

As you may have guessed, the url behind is https://www.gpu-central.com/en/

I have tried the amphtml tag in "rel" too but I have the same error in the end. I don't understand why I need to do this because I have only one single version of each page.

Do you have any idea of what I should do?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: For native AMP, the canonical should be the AMP page itself so it may be a temporary issue with the crawler with AMP pages according to some reports.

Answer (score 1):

The page, https://www.gpu-central.com/en/, as of 2019-01-05, is not a valid AMP page. See https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate to validate the AMP page.